# how to change picture in google app contacts api?

Tags: java, gdata-api, google-contacts-api

**** i want to change the picture in contacts api but i got some exception please check my code

```
String filepath="C:\\Users\\bhanuprasad\\Documents\\Downloads\\549002_459129587462191_1689883124_n.jpg";
    File file = new File(filepath);

    byte[] photoData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
String url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/"+ sDomain + "/full/pcvita1111qaeteam10?xoauth_requestor_id=appsadmin@soharcoas.com" ;
    ContactEntry profile = contactService.getEntry(
            new URL(url),ContactEntry.class);
 GDataRequest request = contactService.createRequest(GDataRequest.RequestType.UPDATE,
          photoUrl, new ContentType("image/jpeg"));

      request.setEtag(photoLink.getEtag());
    OutputStream requestStream = request.getRequestStream();
      requestStream.write(photoData);
     request.execute();
```

when i call request.execute(); i got following exception

com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Bad Request
Invalid image file

```
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:594)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:552)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:530)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535)
```

please help me....

Comment: any one please help me...i struck here since 4 hours....

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code which actually reads your image. You only initialize the byte array using the length of the file. Presumably an uninitialized file is just not a valid image. Get the actual photo data into your byte array and it should work.